# ASP.NET MVC Development tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, expression-blend

Following on from my previous question, If I am beginning to learn asp.net MVC, will the express edition of visual studio web developer be enough, or should I consider the expensive full version of Visual studio. What are the limitation of such express version I may run into? or am I better using an Expression tool? (or is this something I can progress to later.) Any advice anyone? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-sharper (everyones favourite add in ;-)) requires the full version of VS. It's worth getting for that reason alone in my view.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind is lack of the SQL tools in the express versions, such as the Server Explorer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd2cz7yy.aspx). I am not sure if you can effectively do LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities without it.

On that note, I strongly encourage the full version of Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

I know that since you are using the express versions, you qualify for the upgrade price for Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

On a side note: the Expression products are more geared for designers, not coders.

Answer (score 0):

Express is definetly a good start, and if you're just learning you shouldn't miss some of the features from the full version too much. For SQL management, Microsoft now offers SQL Management Studio Express as well (along with SQL Server Express, of course).

The major things that I personally miss when I'm using Express rather than a full version are:

- **Class Diagrams** - these are pretty useful when you're starting off a project and want to map out the classes you'll want to create. With a simple MVC application there probably won't be a huge need for them, however.
- **Attaching to a process for debugging** - Express editions include the full debugger, but you can't attach to an already running process. This is particularly useful if you're using NUnit and you run into a problem and want to debug. There's some workarounds, but they aren't particularly elegant or simple.
- **Integrated testing** - I'm actually surprised this wasn't included - Microsoft should realize that getting new developers to learn good habits like Unit Testing should be encouraged.

The Expression suite is targeted towards designers more than developers. I don't think it's a good fit for what you are looking for.

SharpDevelop is another free option. It's good if you find Express lacking, but I personally don't find the experience as "smooth", and it's particularly short on features relating to web development.

Answer (score 0):

"Full versions" of Visual Studio are not free! If you are beginning to learn asp.net MVC, you shoud try [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) first. Yes, **it does not support integrated testing** but you can use any 3d-party tool ([xUnit](http://www.codeplex.com/xunit) is the best) for testing.